# Cordova store array in sqlite javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, arrays, sqlite, cordova-3

I try to store a array in SQLite with cordova 3.1.0 on my iPhone. The array that i try to store is encoded by json in a php file on my external server. When i get the encoded array on my phone then i try to store it in SQLite.

```
            var JSONstring = data;

            var db = window.openDatabase('DATABASE', "1.0", 'DATABASE', 1000000);
            db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);

            function populateDB(tx) {
                tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DATABASE');
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DATABASE (id unique, data)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DATABASE (id, data) VALUES (1, '+JSONstring+')');
            }

            function errorCB(tx, err) {
                alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
            }

            function successCB() {
                alert("success!");
            }
```

The var JSONstring is the encoded array that i get from my server. But for some reason does my iphone say 'Error processing SQL: undefined'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you'll have to quote the string:

```
 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DATABASE (id, data) VALUES (1, \''+JSONstring+'\')');
```

provided `JSONstring` itself doesn't contain any quotes, otherwise you need to double them (http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q14).

Comment: JSONstring is the variable with the array inside of it

Comment: @MeQube: sqlite doesn't care what it is - it sees only a string, and all strings must be quoted.

Comment: but how can u use that in this form of code?            
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO '+element+'-'+week+' (id, data) VALUES (1, \''+JSONstring+'\')');